# How to store user sql where clause, and how to apply it on a select?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I am using JPA / Eclipselink / PostgreSQL within my application.

I have a model that list some data, and I would like to let the user of the application to create his own *where* clause parameters.

How can I store theses parameters ? as plain sql string ?

Then how can I apply the where clause ? as a simple string concatenation ? (I don't like this idea at all).

Bests regards.

Comment: You really trust the user enough to give him rights to run any query on the db?

Comment: Not really, but I don't have the choice. I will design a part of the application like a wizard that will only permit to select simple check constraints with or and and keywords. In my question, lets asume that the user can't enter full sql as a string, and so that it is not possible to use query like drop table or such.

Comment: since you don't input an SQL string into JPA (unless you really want to lose database independence) then why would you even contemplate storing an SQL string? And you'd have to use some vendor extension to even get the SQL string from EclipseLink

Comment: Yes, I am looking at using jpa criteria api, by decoding some parameters that I have yet to find how to represent. Does using criteria api seems the good way to do it ?

Comment: Criteria API allows you to dynamically create JPQL queries, but then you could write JPQL string-based queries dynamically if you so wanted. Why not just do it and then when you have a problem you use StackOverflow ... which is what this site is for

Comment: I will try to create jpa criteria api from something that represent the user where clause parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved my problem.

For information : I have created a recursive JSON representation of every where clause parameters possibility.

And I have created a query using criteria api by decoding the pojo structure from json.

The json class look like that :

```
public class JSonSearchCriteria
{
    public static enum CriteriaType
    {
        asc,
        desc,
        count,
        countDistinct,
        and,
        or,
        not,
        equal,
        notEqual,
        between,
        gt,
        ge,
        lt,
        le,
        like,
        notLike;
    }

    @Expose
    public CriteriaType             type;

    @Expose
    public List<JSonSearchCriteria> sub;

    @Expose
    public String                   what            = null;

    @Expose
    public List<Integer>            integerValue    = null;

    @Expose
    public List<Long>               longValue       = null;

    @Expose
    public List<Boolean>            booleanValue    = null;

    @Expose
    public List<String>             stringValue     = null;

    @Expose
    public List<DateTime>           datetimeValue   = null;

    public JSonSearchCriteria()
    {
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type, final String what)
    {
        this(type);
        this.what = what;
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type, final String what, final String... values)
    {
        this(type, what);
        for(final String value : values)
        {
            value(value);
        }
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type, final String what, final Long... values)
    {
        this(type, what);
        for(final Long value : values)
        {
            value(value);
        }
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type, final String what, final Integer... values)
    {
        this(type, what);
        for(final Integer value : values)
        {
            value(value);
        }
    }

    public JSonSearchCriteria(final CriteriaType type, final String what, final DateTime... values)
    {
        this(type, what);
        for(final DateTime value : values)
        {
            value(value);
        }
    }

    public void add(final JSonSearchCriteria subCriteria)
    {
        if(sub == null)
        {
            sub = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        sub.add(subCriteria);
    }

    public void value(final String value)
    {
        if(stringValue == null)
        {
            stringValue = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        stringValue.add(value);
    }

    public void value(final Long value)
    {
        if(longValue == null)
        {
            longValue = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        longValue.add(value);
    }

    public void value(final Integer value)
    {
        if(integerValue == null)
        {
            integerValue = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        integerValue.add(value);
    }

    public void value(final DateTime value)
    {
        if(datetimeValue == null)
        {
            datetimeValue = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        datetimeValue.add(value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings(
    {
        "unchecked", "rawtypes"
    })
    @Transient
    public Predicate buildPredicate(final CriteriaBuilder builder, final Root<Record> root, Join<Record, RecordInfo> infos)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case and:
            case or:
                final Predicate[] preds = new Predicate[sub.size()];
                int cpt = 0;
                for(final JSonSearchCriteria s : sub)
                {
                    preds[cpt] = s.buildPredicate(builder, root, infos);
                    cpt++;
                }

                if(type == CriteriaType.and)
                {
                    return builder.and(preds);
                }
                else if(type == CriteriaType.or)
                {
                    return builder.or(preds);
                }
                break;

            case equal:
            case lt:
            case gt:
            case between:
                final Path p;

                if(what.startsWith("infos."))
                {
                    p = infos.get(what.substring(6));
                }
                else
                {
                    p = root.get(what);
                }

                if(stringValue != null && !stringValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    if(type == CriteriaType.equal)
                    {
                        return builder.equal(p, stringValue.get(0));
                    }
                }
                else if(longValue != null && !longValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    if(type == CriteriaType.equal)
                    {
                        return builder.equal(p, longValue.get(0));
                    }
                    else if(type == CriteriaType.lt)
                    {
                        return builder.lt(p, longValue.get(0));
                    }
                    else if(type == CriteriaType.gt)
                    {
                        return builder.gt(p, longValue.get(0));
                    }
                }
                else if(integerValue != null && !integerValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    if(type == CriteriaType.equal)
                    {
                        return builder.equal(p, integerValue.get(0));
                    }
                    else if(type == CriteriaType.lt)
                    {
                        return builder.lt(p, integerValue.get(0));
                    }
                    else if(type == CriteriaType.gt)
                    {
                        return builder.gt(p, integerValue.get(0));
                    }
                }
                else if(booleanValue != null && !booleanValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    return builder.equal(p, booleanValue.get(0));
                }
                else if(datetimeValue != null && !datetimeValue.isEmpty())
                {
                    if(type == CriteriaType.equal)
                    {
                        return builder.equal(p, datetimeValue.get(0));
                    }
                    else if(type == CriteriaType.between && datetimeValue.size() > 1)
                    {
                        return builder.between(p, datetimeValue.get(0), datetimeValue.get(1));
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        System.err.println(type + " - not implemented");
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it is used like that :

```
final SearchTemplate templ = DBHelper.get(SearchTemplate.class, 100);
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeJsonAdapter()).create();
final JSonSearchCriteria crits = gson.fromJson(templ.getTemplate(), JSonSearchCriteria.class);

final CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = DBHelper.getInstance().em().getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Record> critQuery = critBuilder.createQuery(Record.class);
final Root<Record> root = critQuery.from(Record.class);
final Join<Record, RecordInfo> infos = root.join("infos");

critQuery.where(crits.buildPredicate(critBuilder, root, infos));

final TypedQuery<Record> query = DBHelper.getInstance().em().createQuery(critQuery);
final List<Record> result = query.getResultList();

for(final Record rec : result)
{
    System.err.println(rec.toString());
}
```